# Ошибка при компиляции java build.gradle

Tags: java

Вот такое выдаёт при компиляции.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\byToxenskiyAMV\Documents\TabbyChat-2-master\build.gradle' line: 26
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'TabbyChat-2'.

  > Could not get unknown property 'grgit' for root project 'TabbyChat-2' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Comment: Пожалуйста переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык, иначе он будет закрыт из-за несоответствия требованиям данного ресурса.

Comment: build.gradle
line 26 - ext.revision = grgit.log().size()